# What is the correct way to say the days of a month?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

People refer to the days of the month as following:

- 1 de enero = uno de enero o **primero de enero**.
- 2 de enero = dos de enero.
- 3 de enero = tres de enero.

...

**Example**:

> Hoy es primero de enero.

Notice the use of the ordinal number for the **day one**. Does that mean that you can also use ordinal numbers for the days of the month or is this just an exception for the day one?

Would this be correct?

- segundo de enero
- tercero de enero

Comment: French has this different construction too, and in French it's systematic: first, two, three, … [Pourquoi utilise-t-on un ordinal uniquement pour le premier du mois?](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/1553)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of ordinal numbers in dates is an [anglicism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglicism). You can use ordinal or cardinal interchangeably.

There are countries that use only cardinal numbers (like Spain I think):

> 1 (uno) de enero.

In others, we use only the first day of the month as an ordinal:

> 1º (primero) de marzo
>
> 2 (dos) de marzo.
>
> ...

I haven't heard of any country that uses only ordinal numbers but it doesn't mean is wrong. It's also perfectly correct to use:

> 23º (vigésimo tercer día) de junio.

You can found more information on this [blog post](http://usoadecuadodelalenguaescrita.blogspot.com/2009/01/escritura-fechas.html).

Comment: In Spain only cardinal numbers are used, with the exception of "primero" which sounds very archaic nowadays and is rarely used (maybe in very formal settings).

There is a famous song sung in "San Fermín" (the famous running of the bulls on July 7) which says: "uno de enero, dos de febrero, tres de marzo, cuatro de abril, cinco de mayo, seis de junio, siete de julio, ¡San Fermín!" (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mxzr-YcgxKE)

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen or heard of ordinal numbers used for any dates other than the 1st of each month, and then only colloquially. Use cardinal numbers to be safe.